# Randomly swap two elements in an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, random

Is there any way to randomly swap two elements (two different index) in an array in C++? My idea is to randomly pick the first index, then randomly pick the second one till the second index is different from the first index. Then swap these two elements. I am wondering is there any better way to do this?

I think this is different from random_shuffle because each time I only want to swap two elements in the array and keep others in the original order.

Comment: @ZigZagZebra A great idea!:)

Comment: Could you say what this is meant to accomplish?  Picking a better way may depend partly on what this random swap is meant to help you do.

Comment: Is this going to be a one time thing?

Comment: Free hint: [std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, pick two numbers `First` from `[0...N-1]` and `Second` from `[0..N-2]`. If `First` <= `Second` then `++Second` so `Second` ends up in `[0...First-1]` or `[First+1...N-1]`. No retries needed.

Example: Say you have `N=10` so `First` runs from `0-9` inclusive. Imagine you pick `First=5`. You know have 9 elements left from which to pick `Second`, namely `0-4` and `6-9`. You now pick a number `0-8` instead, and map the subrange of possible results `5-8` to `6-9` by adding one.

`<=` is important. If you only added 1 if `First!=Second`, the chances of swapping 5 and 6 would be double, and the chances of swapping 5 and 9 would be 0%.

Comment: Why `First <= Second` and not `First == Second`?

Comment: How about pick First from [0...N-1], second from [0...N-2]. if First == Second, ++Second?

Comment: @ZigZagZebra No. That will clump after the first and never pick the last. We actually need if(second>=first) ++second; Your way has it that if there are 11 elements there's a 20% chance you swap consecutive entries.

Comment: Say you have N=10 so `First` runs from `0-9`. Imagine you pick 5. You know have `9` elements left from which to pick `Second`, `0-4` and `6-9`. You now pick a number `0-8` and map the subrange `5-8` to `6-9` by adding one. If you used `!=`, the chances of swapping 5 and 6 would be double, and the chances of swapping 5 and 9 would be 0%.

Comment: @MSalters I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution based on @MSalters suggestion:

```
int first = randInt(myArray.size()-1);
int second = randInt(myArray.size()-1);
while (first == second) {
    second = randInt(myArray.size()-1);
}
char firstLetter = letters[first];
char secondLetter = letters[second];
myArray[first] = secondLetter;
myArray[second] = firstLetter;
```